# How to duplicate all apps on 1 laptop and install on another?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I am setting up 20 laptops for a school and I want to use the same Lubuntu setup and applications on all laptops.

All of the laptops are old and are different hardware.

I have set up 1 successfully already.

Is there a way to streamline the installation process so that they all have the same applications?

It would need to use usb flash drives rather than cd/dvd.

I tried aptoncd and it did not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the same version of Lubuntu is running on all the systems, eg 14.04, the you can do the following -

On the primary machine, ie the one which you wish to clone, run the command -

`dpkg --get-selections > list.txt`

This will save the names of all the packages installed on the system in a file named `list.txt`.

Now copy this file to the other computers and run the following commands -

`dpkg --set-selections < list.txt`

`sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`

You may additionally copy the contents of `/var/cache/apt/archives` from the primary system and paste it in the corresponding locations of the other systems to avoid downloading the packages again on each system.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple method, take Software system's help:
Ubuntu software center has a feature of "syncing installed softwares between computers"

[image: Ubuntu software center]

Answer (score 0):

advanced users and if the PCs are all connected to the same network can take a look at [Clonezilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla).

---

if you just have a list of the programs you installed additionally, you can use this command in the terminal after the installation of the base-system:

```
xargs -a /path/to/your/'program list' sudo apt-get install
```

the list must have only one program-name per line and unix-line-endings (will be the default if you created the file under Linux)!

you will be asked for the superuser-password, the programs from your file and all dependencies will be listed, you can check them and have to confirm the installation-process.

---

maybe you will also copy the hidden files from the home-directory of the "master-PC" to the new PCs... so your user-settings (and ONLY user-settings) will be copied!